# WCDMA only option in Jelly bean devices

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

Earlier versions of Android did have this "WCDMA only" option for connecting to cellular network. However with Jelly bean there's none.

Its really frustrating especially when the Android OS keeps on connecting to 2G where in the same spot 3G is very much available.

Is there a way to force WCDMA only with Jelly Bean, I've tried `*#*#4636#*#*` but nothing happened.

**Update:**

I'm using Android 4.1.1

Comment: I have the option on my phone... Sony Xperia SP 4.1.2

Comment: It might help to specify which device, ROM, and Android-Version (there are multiple Jelly-Bean-versions from 4.1 to 4.3) you are using.